# Grails 2.3.8 dependency resolution

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have 2 plugins - plugin A and plugin B.

Plugin B contains a domain class.I have then used the command - grails package-plugin on the plugin B.

I have declared the plugin dependency in the buildconfig.groovy of plugin A like below:

```
 plugins {      
     build(":release:3.0.1",
          ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
        export = false
    }
    compile ":plugin-b:0.1"
 }
```

I have created a service class in plugin A, which uses the domain class from plugin B. 
Now, When I try to refresh-dependencies on plugin A / or do a package-plugin on plugin A, it gives me error that it is not able to find the domain class from plugin b.

Any one has any idea if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell grails that plugin A depends on plugin B by adding a `dependsOn` to plugin A.

```
class APlugin {
  def dependsOn = [B : "<version>"]
}
```

See [Plugin load order](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#understandingPluginLoadOrder) in the Grails documentation.

Comment: I added the "dependsOn" to Plugin A. But, still not able to resolve.It is failing because it is not able to find the pluginB.zip.It complains that plugin B not found. What other things do I need to include beside the "dependsOn" ?

Comment: hmm, the dependsOn will help if you have a project that uses both plugins. If it is project using plugin A which uses plugin B it should work like in your original code. Did you install the plugins into your local maven repository?